# Copy-PnPFile Not Working Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: Null value for source item at

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

I'm tying to use Copy-PnPFile command to copy all files and folders from site collection A document library to another site collection B/folder but it's not working. Following is the command I'm using:

```
Copy-PnPFile -SourceUrl "/sites/AshTest/Docs" -TargetUrl "/sites/ADM-AshTest/TestDocs/Docs" -Force
```

Error:

```
Copy-PnPFile : {"odata.error":{"code":"-2147467261, System.ArgumentNullException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: Null value for source item at
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/AshTest/Docs"}}}
At line:1 char:1
+ Copy-PnPFile -SourceUrl "/sites/AshTest/Docs" -TargetUrl "/sites/ADM- ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : WriteError: (:) [Copy-PnPFile], HttpRequestException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,PnP.PowerShell.Commands.Files.CopyFile
```

Please let me know what can be done to make it work.

Comment: I am currently doing some research on this issue, will let you know as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my research, `Copy-PnPFile` does not work on the root folder of a library.

Here is a similar issue for reference: https://github.com/pnp/powershell/issues/410